# Catan Seafarers discovery question

Tags: catan-seafarers

In Catan Seafarers, in a scenario like Fog Island where hexes are unknown, can you build a settlement  at an intersection of a known hex and an unknown hex and if you can, do you uncover the unknown hex or does it remain a mystery until a ship actually is adjacent to it?

Answer (score 2):

From p12 of [the rules](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?Seafarers_rv_Rules_091907.pdf) (emphasis added),

> If you place a ship or road that connects to the **intersection** of an unexplored hex, you must immediately draw the top hex from the pile and place it face up in the empty space.

If you can ever build a settlement on an intersection, you must already have a road/ship connected to that intersection, so all those hexes should already be explored; exploring does *not* require a road/ship to be built on one of the hex's *edges*.